# Output SDL to TFT screen from console

Tags: touchscreen, terminal, pitft, sdl

I'm trying to make a SDL program (fastdosbox) output to an adafruit TFT screen. The screen is fb1. In the console I tried typing SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb1 but it still outputs to the HDMI screen. If I startx and then load fastdosbox, it will work, but it's not useable with all the other stuff on the screen and I'd like to run it directly from the console. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a tool called [fbcopy](https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) that will duplicate on the TFT what's being sent to HDMI.

Here is a working tutorial on [How to mirror/copy the HDMI output to the display](https://github.com/watterott/RPi-Display/blob/master/docu/FAQ.md#how-to-mirrorcopy-the-hdmi-output-to-the-display).